Meaning of ./texmf-dist/source/ directory in TexLive TDS
What is the meaning of the directory ./texmf-dist/source/ in TexLive?
It is quite heavy for the TexLive profile scheme-basic: 22 megabytes
Is it used during LaTex compilation by any LaTeX programs?
Can I safely delete this directory? (for the same goals of reducing space and similar to deletion of ./texmf-dist/doc/ as discussed in Removing texmf/doc/ directories from old TeXlives)

Context: I am interested in maximal disk space reduction of a TexLive TDS because I'm distributing it over Internet for further use with in-browser WASM compiled LaTeX programs), so safely stripping off 22 megabytes would be really nice. I'm also interested what else can be stripped / compressed :) Also interested, how to generate the *.pk files at install-tl time
Thanks!

I thought there was an option in the installer to omit the source tree?

Hmm, should I use --no-doc-install --no-src-install?

Please feel free to write the same as an answer, I'll accept it

The source subtree must be offered in order to comply with the requirements for “free software” (ask the Debian people, for instance).
One might argue that macro packages (generic term for every flavor of TeX, not necessarily LaTeX only) are sources of themselves. Even files such as plain.tex and latex.ltx that aren't used at run time are anyway present in the tex subtree, because they're needed at format creation.
However the material in source contains much more than the files input when TeX is run: most of them contain commented code which the macro packages and documentation are derived from and there are often also example files, whose typeset representation may be available in doc.
If you're not interested in the source files, you can safely ask tlmgr not to install them: they're never needed at runtime. Well, unless some packaging fails; this sometimes happens, but is usually fixed in a day or two.
The doc subtree is available online at TeXdoc.org (beware that it's not updated daily, so it might not always have the most recent information).
The machine I'm writing on has all TeX Live distributions from 2012 up to 2024 and
du -hs /usr/local/texlive

prints out 87G. Such a figure would be unimaginable for the first hard disk I installed TeX on, which had a whopping 20M capacity (a heavy and noisy brick). Disk space is quite cheap nowadays, so I don't see any need to remove the source or doc subtrees.

Thanks for your response!
For my usecase, I'm building a single statically-linked WASM executable with latex programs builtin (pdftex, xetex, bibtex) and a basic TDS. As it's expected to be downloaded by the browser, it's nice to have the basic binary under 50 Megabytes.

@VadimKantorov In this case it's perfectly reasonable to cut source, doc and probably most of the fonts subtree (the opentype and truetype parts, I mean).
